# How to implement termstore query in content query webpart editor

Tags: 2010, content-query-web-part, term-store

I am creating a content query webpart (in SharePoint 2010) that displays documents that have been tagged with a particular termstore tag. The issue I am having is how to create the content query webpart editor so that  it allows the user to select which termstore tag to use for the display.

The image below shows what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

The first line allows the user to select the term-set. The second line allows the user to select the selection criteria. The last line allow the user to select from a list of available tags under the selected term-set.

How would one go about implementing this functionality? I understand how to create a webpart editor, but not functions needed to get termstore items and present them in a nice selectable list. I suspect that I need to store this information by term GUID so that if the term changes name, the display will update automatically.

Please provide sample code on how one would go about accomplishing this.

Thanks.